# Maximal full-mesh in a graph - python code is very slow

Tags: python, performance, graph

I have some python code for computing the maximal full-mesh in a graph. Each node of the graph can have a different weight (The weights of each node are given by an array). I want to get the maximal weighted-clique size in the graph, given the edges that are not present. I wrote some python code for this that works as follows:

1. I start with the fully-connected graph where all edges are present.
2. If an edge is broken in a fully-connected graph, it will break it into two fully-connected graphs (split_full_meshes method below).
3. Finally, I sum the weights across all possible cliques and get the clique with maximal weight.

The code is included below (maximal_full_mesh calculates the maximal weighted clique while split_full_meshes is a helper for splitting cliques). The problem is that it is painfully slow. I need to be able to run this in a loop of 2 million (all possible graphs with seven nodes), but it takes a full 10 minutes to run. I'm looking for suggestions on how I can make this faster.

```
def split_full_meshes(meshes=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3]], broken_edge=[0,1]):
    """
    A full mesh is defined as a series of nodes that
    are all interconnected with each other. When we break an edge,
    any full-mesh that has both nodes corresponding to that edge will be 
    broken up
    into two smaller full-meshes.
    args:
        meshes: A jagged array, each entry is an array of indices of nodes 
            that are full-mesh connected.
        broken_edge: The edge that was not earlier broken but is now going
                 to be broken.
    """
    nu_meshes = []
    for mesh in meshes:
        if broken_edge[0] in mesh and broken_edge[1] in mesh:
            for node in broken_edge:
                nu_meshes.append([i for i in mesh if i!= node])
        else:
            nu_meshes.append(np.copy(mesh))
    return nu_meshes


def maximal_full_mesh(a=np.array([2,2,3,4]), \
    broken_edges=np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])):
    """
    The largest weighted full-mesh available in the graph.
    (set of nodes with perfect interconnectivity with each other).
    args:
        a: The weights of each node in the graph.
        broken_edges: The edges between nodes that are broken.
    """
    meshes = [np.arange(len(a))]
    for ed in broken_edges:
        meshes_tmp = np.copy(meshes)
        meshes = split_full_meshes(meshes_tmp, ed)
    max_mesh = 0
    for mesh in meshes:
        max_mesh = max(max_mesh, sum(a[np.array(mesh)]))
    return max_mesh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I tackle the problem in reverse- I generate the sets of nodes to exclude from the original full-mesh to make each resulting full-mesh. From this, I can easily use a few tricks- skipping over edges that aren't contained in the corresponding full mesh using set differences, and pruning sub optimal branches early as they exceed the weight threshold.

```
class FullMesh:
    def __init__(self, pairs, weights):
        self.pairs = pairs
        self.weights = weights
        self.elements = set(range(len(weights)))

        self.skips = {e:set() for e in self.elements}
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(pairs):
            self.skips[a].add(i)
            self.skips[b].add(i)

    def find_max(self):
        max_score = sum(self.weights)
        val, nums = self.exclude(0, max_score + 1, set(range(len(self.pairs))))
        return max_score - val, sorted(self.elements - set(nums))

    def exclude(self, curr_score, min_score, search):
        if not search or min_score <= curr_score:
            return curr_score, []

        min_nums = []
        for e in self.pairs[next(iter(search))]:
            score, nums = self.exclude(curr_score + self.weights[e], min_score, search - self.skips[e])
            if score < min_score:
                min_score, min_nums = score, nums + [e]
        return min_score, min_nums
```

Comment: This is indeed much faster and produces the same result! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @RohitPandey Its also worth mentioning that if you are working on all possible graphs of n nodes, you can reuse information from the solution to compute a few future graphs. Any combination of two nodes cut from a prior solution can be freely added to that graphs broken_edges list without changing the answer. So use that to compute the solution for every combination of every combination of two cut nodes + original broken_edges.

Comment: Thanks! I am looping over all possible graphs of n nodes. Don't concretely understand your comment about re-using broken_edges (but very eager to)? Is this going to help reduce the 2^{n \choose 2} graphs I have to loop over.

Comment: It is hard to say in terms of Big-O because both methods of pruning the search space depend on the weights passed, but amortized time complexity will probably decrease. The idea is that if your Full-Mesh solution for some `broken_edges` is `13 : [1, 3, 4]` for some weights, then the cut nodes are `[0, 2, 5]`. We can then say the graph `broken_edges` + `[(0, 2)]` also has the same solution, because we already cut both 0 and 2 from the graph. The same holds for `broken_edges` + `[(0,2), (0, 5)]`, and `[(2,5), (0, 5)]`, etc.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks, it does look like this will speed things up. There might even be a way to save all the graphs to disk. Lots of experimentation ahead. Again, this was a life-saver.

Comment: @RohitPandey it just occurred to me, both numbers `(x, y)` don't have but be cut nodes, only one. So for the above example, `broken_edges` + `[(0, x)]`, and `broken_edges` + `[(2, y), (5, z)]` are all valid for **any** x, y, or z in the nodes.

Comment: It solved the problem for all subgraphs of a 7-node graph in ~50sec on my machine.

Comment: Nice.. was the 50 sec with the optimization of re-using the subgraphs? If so, do you have the code for that handy?

Comment: @RohitPandey It was. However, this question was specifically about optimizing code for an arbitrary graph's full-mesh, any future readers likely won't be concerned with n-node subgraph optimizations, so I feel like this probably isn't the place for it. If you are willing to post a follow up question regarding tweaking the above code for n-node subgraphs, I'd be happy to put up my code there. Just be sure to @ mention me.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Just posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643883/efficiently-loop-through-all-possible-graphs-of-weighted-nodes-and-calculate-the