# Efficiently loop through all possible graphs of weighted nodes and calculate the probability that the maximal clique size is >k

Tags: python, performance, graph

This question is a follow up to this other one: [Maximal full-mesh in a graph - python code is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622759/maximal-full-mesh-in-a-graph-python-code-is-very-slow).

That one was about finding the maximal clique size in a weighted sub-graph. My ultimate objective was to find the probability that a graph with connections having probabilities q of being active and some weights on all its nodes would have a maximal weighted clique size greater than k. For this, I would loop over all possible graphs on the n nodes and add to the probability if the maximal weighted clique size was >=k. However, @Dillon Davis mentioned in the other question that there is a way to make this more efficient. So, posting this question to see if anyone can help make the looping over graphs more efficient by re-using graphs computed earlier. Posting my code that does a naive loop for reference.

```
def networking_resiliency(k=4, q=0.5, wts=np.ones(4)):    
    edges = []
    n = len(wts)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            edges.append((i,j))
    edges = np.array(edges)
    ans = 0.0
    for e_idx in range(2**len(edges)):
        arr = to_binary(e_idx, len(edges))
        broken_edges = edges[arr==0]
        if type == "full_mesh":
            fm = FullMesh(broken_edges,wts)
            if fm.find_max()[0] >= k:
                up_edges = sum(arr)
                ans += q**up_edges*(1-q)**(len(edges)-up_edges)        
    return ans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to compute the optimal full-mesh of some graphs from other computed graphs. For a given full-mesh, if we note the nodes that have been cut from the original graph to produce the current sub graph, we find that any other edges connecting to these cut nodes can freely but cut without consequence. Using this information, we can take the Cartesian product of the cut nodes and all other nodes, remove any equivalent duplicates, and have a set of all edges we can freely cut. We then take the powerset of all these edges, and concatenate each to our current list of broken edges to determine a other subgraphs that will inevitably result in the same optimal full-mesh. The modified FullMesh class that implements this behavior can be seen below:

```py
class FullMesh:
    def __init__(self, weights, pairs=[]):
        self.weights = weights
        self.elements = set(range(len(weights)))
        self.set_pairs(pairs)

    def set_pairs(self, pairs):
        self.pairs = pairs
        self.skips = {e:set() for e in self.elements}
        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(pairs):
            self.skips[a].add(i)
            self.skips[b].add(i)

    def powerset(self, elements):
        return chain.from_iterable(combinations(elements, r) for r in range(len(elements)+1))

    def find_all(self):
        to_search = self.powerset(list(combinations(self.elements, 2)))
        pairs_searched = dict()
        for pairs in to_search:
            if pairs in pairs_searched: continue
            self.set_pairs(pairs)
            val, nums = self.find_max()
            new_pairs = set(product(set(self.elements) - set(nums), set(self.elements))) - set(pairs)
            new_pairs = self.powerset({(x, y) for x, y in new_pairs if x < y})
            pairs_searched.update({tuple(sorted(pairs + np)):(val,nums) for np in new_pairs})
        return pairs_searched

    def find_max(self):
        max_score = sum(self.weights)
        val, nums = self.exclude(0, max_score + 1, set(range(len(self.pairs))))
        return max_score - val, sorted(self.elements - set(nums))

    def exclude(self, curr_score, min_score, search):
        if not search or min_score <= curr_score:
            return curr_score, []

        min_nums = []
        for e in self.pairs[next(iter(search))]:
            score, nums = self.exclude(curr_score + self.weights[e], min_score, search - self.skips[e])
            if score < min_score:
                min_score, min_nums = score, nums + [e]
        return min_score, min_nums
```

This code took ~50sec to produce all optimal full-meshes for all sub graphs of a randomly weighted, 7-node fully-connected graph.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, these optimizations and others I was inspired to make looking at your code helped me bring the run time of some probability computations from 20 minutes to a few seconds. This allowed me to make them available in an online service which was impossible before. Again, much appreciated!

Comment: @RohitPandey I'm to hear that! Mind if I ask though- what were the nature of the optimizations you made? I'm sure there are plenty of small micro-optimizations I overlooked, but if there's any algorithmic improvements I'd be very interested in hearing about them.

Comment: the optimizations were not to your function. There was a layer above where I would loop through all possible weight configurations of the nodes. Some of these configurations ended up collapsing to be the same, so I just maintained a hash set and didn't recompute if I'd seen the weight configuration before. Further, many users of the online service were using just a handful of values of q (the probabilities of the edges being alive). So, I stored the probabilities corresponding to a graph and q as well in memory. None of it was super sophisticated/ algorithmically innovative.